# How to add transformer pipe to http?

Tags: angular

I wont to do some transformer to all my responses:

```
  post(url, body) {
    return this.httpClient.post(url, body).pipe((result) => transform(result));
  } 

transform(data){
data = ...
return data;
}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a `map` for that.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

post(url, body) {
    return this.httpClient.post(url, body).pipe(map(result => this.transform(result)));
}

transform(data){
    data = ...
    return data;
}
```

Comment: FYI you can just do map(this.transform) as map takes a function as it's argument.

Comment: @bryan60 That's a bad idea almost anywhere in typescript, since that won't bind the `this` context to the transform function.

Comment: of course it will. it is defined in the this context... also... your map function should be pure and not rely on external state

Comment: @bryan60 No it's not binded. I suggest you try it yourself.

Comment: Depends how you define your function dude. The issue is when you do or don’t create new scope and it primarily matters when accessing injected services. As a matter of habit I’ll define them like: fn = (args) => val if you do fn(args) { return val } then no, you’ll create new score. But your blanket statement that you create new scope by binding the way i recommended is incorrect. It’s better to understand when scope is created and when it’s not and act accordingly to the use case.